Expor-tos. Como explicar esta construção?
Comecei a ler o livro de José Saramago "O Evangelho segundo Jesus Cristo". Logo na primeira página, o autor faz uma citação de Lucas 1, 1-14. Lá ele escreve:

(...) resolvi eu também, depois de tudo ter investido cuidadosamente desde a origem, expor-tos por escrito e pela sua ordem, ilustre Teófilo, a fim de que reconheças a solidez da doutrina em que foste instruído.

Como explicar esta construção "expor-tos"?

O pronome oblíquo "-tos" é contração de "-te" com "-os", portanto o que seria "*-te-los". Expor-tos significa "expô-los a ti".
Uma tabela pode ser encontrada aqui https://blog.flaviarita.com/pronome-pessoal-obliquo/#CONTRACAO_DOS_PRONOMES_OBLIQUOS_ATONOS

A explicação e a tabela foram muito úteis. Obrigado @Quaestoria.
